# Showing a subspace is closed

Tags: normed-spaces, complete-spaces

> Let $X = (\textbf{c}_{0},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ and $Y$ be defined as 
>   $$
>     Y := \bigg\{ \{x_{i}\} \in \textbf{c}_{0} : \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{i}}{2^{i}} = 0 \bigg\}.
> $$
>
> (1) Show that $Y$ is a complete subspace of $X$.

Since $X$ is Banach, it is complete. So, it suffices to show that $Y$ is closed in $X$. Let $y \in \overline{Y}$, then there exists $\{y_{n}\} \subset Y$ such that $y_{n} \to y$ as $n \to \infty$. I don't know where to go from here...

In addition, how may these be shown?

> (2) For $x = (2,0,0,\ldots) \in \textbf{c}_{0}$, show that $d_{\infty}(x,Y) = 1$.
>
> (3) Show that there exists no $y \in Y$ satisfying $\|x-y\|_{\infty} = d_{\infty}(x,Y)$.

Comment: you have a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $X$, and for each one : $\sum_i \frac{x_{n}(i)}{2^i} = 0$. and $x_n \to x$ in $X$, so what about $\sum_i \frac{x(i)}{2^i}$ ?

Comment: (after do the same with the subspace of $X$ where $\sum_i x(i)  = 0$ and compare)